Magnetic dipole field from vector potential
The magnetic dipole field:
$$\textbf{B}=\frac{\mu_0I}{4\pi}\frac{3(\textbf{m}\cdot\hat{\textbf{x}})\hat{\textbf{x}}-\textbf{m}}{r^3}$$
can be calculated from the vector potential $\textbf{A}$ and magnetic moment $\textbf{m}$, where:
$$\textbf{m}=\frac{1}{2}\int \textbf{x}'\times\textbf{J}(x')\hspace{1mm}d^3x'$$
This can be done with spherical coordinates and that's fine, but I'm trying to do it with index notation and have some problems getting it right. Starting with the vector potential:
$$\textbf{A}(\textbf{x})=\frac{\mu_0I}{4\pi}\frac{\textbf{m}\times\textbf{x}}{|x|^3}=\frac{\mu_0I}{4\pi r^3}\epsilon_{ijk}m_jx_k$$
For simpicity, I omit the $\frac{\mu_0I}{4\pi r^3}$ term from here. The dipole field is then:
$$\textbf{B}=\nabla \times \textbf{A}=\epsilon_{ijk}\partial_j A_k =\epsilon_{ijk}\partial_j(\epsilon_{mnk}m_mx_n)=\epsilon_{ijk}\epsilon_{mnk}\partial_jm_mx_n $$
Noting that $\epsilon_{mnk}=\epsilon_{kmn}$ we use the $\epsilon-\delta$ identity:
$$\Longrightarrow \textbf{B}=(\delta_{in}\delta_{jm}-\delta_{im}\delta_{jn})\partial_jm_mx_n=\partial_im_jx_i-\partial_im_ix_j$$
Now using the product rule:
$$\textbf{B}=m_j\partial_ix_i + x_i\partial_im_j - m_i\partial_i x_j -x_j\partial_im_i$$
I think the terms with $\partial_{\alpha} m_{\beta}$ are zero because $\text{m}$ depends only on $\textbf{x}'$, so now:
$$\textbf{B}=m_j\partial_i x_i-m_i\partial_ix_j$$
Here's where it gets a little confusing. I know $\partial_ix_i=3$ and $\partial_ix_j=\delta_{ij}$. But I'm not sure how to treat the unit vectors (some people and textbooks do this with unit vectors all the way and some seem to omit them altoghether). I get:
$$\textbf{B}=\frac{\mu_0I}{4\pi r^3}(m_j\hat{e}_j\partial_i x_i-m_i\partial_ix_j)=\frac{\mu_0I}{4\pi r^3}(3m_j\hat{e}_j-m_i\delta_{ij})=\frac{\mu_0I}{4\pi}\frac{3\textbf{m}\cdot\hat{\textbf{x}}-\textbf{m}}{r^3}$$
and this is not right. I think I'm on the right track but I'm using the unit vector incorrectly. Can someone help me out here?

$r=|\mathbf {x-x'}|$, why can you ignore the the derivative of $r^{-3}$ with respect to $\mathbf x$?

@hyportnex: I took it as a magnitude that can be factored out. but thanks for pointing it out. I'll see what happens with it included

$\nabla_i | \vec{x}|=x_i/|\vec{x}|$ should cure the disease.

Your notation is somewhat sloppy. In place of $$\textbf{A}(\textbf{x})=\frac{\mu_0I}{4\pi}\frac{\textbf{m}\times\textbf{x}}{|x|^3}=\frac{\mu_0I}{4\pi r^3}\epsilon_{ijk}m_jx_k$$
you should write $$A_i(\textbf{x})=\frac{\mu_0I}{4\pi}\frac{(\textbf{m}\times\textbf{x})i}{|x|^3}=\frac{\mu_0I}{4\pi r^3}\epsilon{ijk}m_jx_k$$
and so on.

thanks guys, your contributions helped here and I nailed it! I already knew what you pointed out but sloppy is my middle name so....
